# What is a good overlapping groups algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, graph, cluster-analysis, data-visualization, social-networking

I am familiar with various clustering algorithms (k-means etc) but for my specific use case (social networks), I need an algorithm that detects **overlapping** groups. This algorithm neatly separates my Facebook friends into my high school friends, my college friends, my family and my work friends.

The algorithm I used above (JUNG's VoltageClusterer) separates nodes into single clusters. But I want an algorithm that can assign nodes multiple clusters (e.g. a friend of mine can be both my high school friend and college friend).

How do I do this? It would be nice if I can have this algorithm work for weighted graphs too instead of just unweighted ones.

Comment: Google for "fuzzy clustering" and/or "soft clustering", and you should find quite a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Palla et al have a nice Nature paper on detecting overlapping communities:
http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v435/n7043/full/nature03607.html
They demonstrate its success in different types of networks, from social to protein interaction.

The algorithm is called k-clique percolation. It's implemented in their C-finder program:
http://www.cfinder.org/

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question, I found a decent paper: http://www.springerlink.com/content/y44484587755k478/

Any other papers/approaches would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You might try fuzzy c-means, which is much like the old standby, k-means, but permits overlapping clusters.  There is a reasonable introduction (including a small demonstration) at:

[A Tutorial on Clustering Algorithms: Fuzzy c-Means](http://home.dei.polimi.it/matteucc/Clustering/tutorial_html/cmeans.html)